What is wrong with our `sdSpiSendCommand()` that doesn't work communicating through SPI?
We're trying to communicate with en eMMC MTFC8GAM thourh the eUSCI SPI interface of the MSP.
This eMMC does support 1-bit data mode.
We're not able to make it work for now though. We did some research and actually discovered that SPI interface has been removed from MMC standard in the latest versions.
What we're not able to understand is what prevents us from communicating to the eMMC card following the MMC protocol with an SPI interface.
Previously we were using an SD card and it worked fine. For testing purpose we used the same PCB and just soldered wires to connect pin-to-pin from the SD card reader to our eMMC.
Software wise, we were already using the SD card in SPI mode, based on the Datasheet standards of MMC and SD card, the format of the commands are the same, so we kept that part, we changed the response handling however. This doesn't matter too much for now because we're not getting any response anyway.
We also checked with an oscilloscope that data and clock are sent correctly to the eMMC, but as mentionned previously we're not getting anything back.
Our "pinout" is the following one:

SPI pin MOSI --> eMMC pin CMD
SPI pin MISO --> eMMC pin DAT0
SPI pin CLK --> eMMC pin CLK
MSP430 gpio P3.0 --> eMMC DAT3 (CS ?). We drive this gpio to logic state low before writing to CMD and drive back to logic high afterward.

Here what our code to send a command to the eMMC looks like (used to work with SD cards):
static void sdSpiSendCommand(unsigned char *res, unsigned bufferLength)
{
    unsigned int tries = 0;
    unsigned char crc = 0;
    unsigned int i;

    // sdCardCommand.command is the command id, 0 for init, 24 for write block etc
    // sdCardCommand.params is an uint32_t containing the command arguments
    const unsigned char rawCommand[5] = {
        0x40 | sdCardCommand.command,
        (sdCardCommand.params >> 24) & 0xFF,
        (sdCardCommand.params >> 16) & 0xFF,
        (sdCardCommand.params >> 8) & 0xFF,
        sdCardCommand.params & 0xFF};

    pinClear(SDCARD_CS); // Assert CS line to low level

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(rawCommand); i++) {
        crc = crc7Tab[(crc << 1) ^ rawCommand[i]];

        // sdSSpiSendByte() both write a byte then read one which is returned
        sdSpiSendByte(rawCommand[i]);
    }

    sdSpiSendByte((crc << 1) | 0x01); // send CRC-7 followed by end bit

    do {
        if (++tries > SD_CMD_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT) {
            pinSet(SDCARD_CS);
            sdStatus |= SDCARD_CMD_TIMEOUT;
            return;
        }
        res[0] = sdSpiSendByte(0xFF);
    } while (res[0] == 0xFF); // There is a pull-up on DAT0, which means 0xFF is read if nothing is sent by the eMMC

    // Usually for MMC format, command response is 6 bytes
    for (i = 1; i < bufferLength; ++i) {
        res[i] = sdSpiSendByte(0xFF);
    }

    pinSet(SDCARD_CS);
}

So we're aware that "SPI mode" was removed from MMC standard but what does "SPI mode" even represent for the eMMC? At the end of the day we're just putting high and low levels on the line that goes to CMD pin of the eMMC, that's why we don't see why SPI couldn't be viable for that.
What is wrong with our sdSpiSendCommand() function that would explain it doesn't work?

I never heard that MMC supported SPI wiring (yes, it supports 1-bit mode, but it's on the level of protocol). On contrary SD does support SPI connections up to the recent cards (however not all of them has to support it).
